# PowerShell search file and display the result

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements, powershell-cmdlet

I want to search for a file in my C: and E: driver. If the file exists and then displays "File exists" Else: display File does not exist. I create the following code:

```
$filename = 'Myfile.exe'

Get-Childitem -Path C:\\, E:\\ -Include $filename -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}

$filename = 'Myfile.exe'
"Test to see if file $filename  exists"
if (Test-Path -Path $filename) {
    "file exists!"
} else {
    "File doesn't exist."
}
```

Note: Myfile may be in a different folder

When I run my scripts, I can see myfile.exe, but the result is  "File doesn't exist."

What is wrong with my scripts?

Comment: At the moment line 2 outputs the file(/s) it found, and the rest of the script only looks for `Myfile.exe`  in the current directory. You need to move your code inside the foreach (`%{}`) block braces - that way your code will execute for each file found matching your criteria

Comment: Hi Mistersmith, Do you mean I update my code to : Get-Childitem -Path C:\\, E:\\ -Include $filename -Recurse | (%{$_.FullName})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, your `Get-ChildItem` alone should suffice to let you know it's found the file by printing it's full path. Anyways, as [MisterSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4438168/mistersmith) mentions in his comment, you would need to place your conditional statements inside your `Foreach-Object` to get your expected result.

Here's my take on this:

```
$filename = 'Myfile.exe'
if (Get-Childitem -Path "C:\", "E:\" -Include $filename -Recurse -OutVariable "Found") {
    Write-Output -InputObject "File exists!"
    #$found.FullName
}
else {
    Write-Output -InputObject "File doesn't exist."
}
```

Leveraging PowerShell's flexibility of allowing the entirety of the expression to be placed inside your `if()` statement, that's all you would need here. Once the file is found, have it output that the file exists, else, say it doesn't.

- The `-OutVariable` parameter allows you to save the object to a variable (`$found`) in case you need to reference any of it's properties later on.